# Manjaro (KDE) running as a rdp server

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, kde, remote-control, kde-plasma-5

Simple question, but difficult to solve... So far... =|

How to make **Manjaro (KDE)** work as a rdp **server**?

**NOTES:**
**I** - We really like the rdp protocol and have used it in the past with other Linux distros (Ubuntu) as a server, but we are having a hard time getting rdp to work on Manjaro (KDE) as a server;
**II** - We know that there are many other options for remote access, but our usage reality requires we to use RDP, so please we ask that all answers deal **exclusively with an rdp solution**.

Thanks! =D

**INTERESTING LINKS ABOUT THE SUBJECT:**

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/xrdp-cant-get-plasma-to-start-after-initial-logging-into-xrdp-xorg-session/110678

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/not-able-to-rdp-from-windows-to-manjaro-vm-via-xrdp-xorg/94357/2

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrdp

---

**UPDATE:**

We have really been trying to get rdp (xrdp) to work with Manjaro KDE (KDE5), but we are having a lot of difficulties... =|

We use a lot of documentation and information on the internet especially in these links...

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/linux-vm-tools/master/arch/install-config.sh

https://www.hiroom2.com/2019/06/15/ubuntu-1904-xrdp-kde-en/

Apparently it is possible to make xrdp work with KDE 5, but we couldn't make it work with Manjaro KDE...

**CURRENT SITUATION:**

. LOG xrdp-sesman

`less +F /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log`

```
[20191211-14:03:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20191211-14:03:27] [INFO ] Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log  
[20191211-14:03:37] [ERROR] X server for display 10 startup timeout
[20191211-14:03:37] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 5102) to exit
[20191211-14:03:37] [ERROR] X server for display 10 startup timeout
[20191211-14:03:37] [ERROR] another Xserver might already be active on display 10 - see log
[20191211-14:03:37] [DEBUG] aborting connection...
[20191211-14:03:37] [CORE ] window manager (pid 5102) did exit, cleaning up session
[20191211-14:03:37] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 5101
[20191211-14:03:37] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20191211-14:03:37] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_10
[20191211-14:03:37] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdpapi_10
[20191211-14:03:37] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: failed to delete /tmp/.xrdp/xrdpapi_10
[20191211-14:03:37] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username eduardolac, display :10.0, session_pid 5101, ip 192.168.12.1:33886 - socket: 1
```

. LOG xrdp

`less +F /var/log/xrdp.log`

```
[20191211-14:05:19] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 192.168.12.253:3389)
[20191211-14:05:19] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET connection received from 192.168.12.1 port 34186
[20191211-14:05:19] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 192.168.12.253:3389)
[20191211-14:05:19] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:3389)
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20191211-14:05:19] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20191211-14:05:19] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20191211-14:05:19] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 3, selected 0
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] connected client computer name: eduardo-nb
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1004 flags 0xc0a00000
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0800000
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] Non-TLS connection established from 192.168.12.1 port 34186: encrypted with standard RDP security
[20191211-14:05:19] [DEBUG] xrdp_00001455_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000416.ini
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000416.ini
[20191211-14:05:19] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20191211-14:05:19] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000416 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20191211-14:05:20] [DEBUG] Closed socket 23 (AF_UNIX)
```

. Remmina Behavior

It is oscillating between two screens as this image...

[image: Remmina behavior]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your Manjaro KDE (KDE 5, Plasma 5) remotely (thanks to @AJSlye ) via Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) install FreeRDP ( http://www.freerdp.com/ )...

**NOTE:** FreeRDP is a free implementation of the Micro$$oft's RDP - Remote Desktop Protocol.

`pacman -S --noconfirm freerdp`

After installing FreeRDP open a terminal and run (on your server) the `freerdp-shadow-cli` command with the user you want to use to log in remotely...

[image: freerdp-shadow-cli]

For RDP client (Manjaro KDE) we recommend KRDC...

`pacman -S --noconfirm krdc`

[image: krdc]

---

**FINAL CONSIDERATIONS:**

We really like the FreeRDP as a server ("freerdp-shadow-cli"), it looks very light and is extremely simple. If it were integrated with the service manager (like "systemctl") then it would be perfect! The lack of documentation on "freerdp-shadow-cli" bothered us a bit.

We have other options like xrdp ( http://xrdp.org/ ), but it seems that xrdp has not been updated as FreeRDP and has limited support for Manjaro and/or KDE 5. We would like to see it working to compare...

---

**FURTHER QUESTION:**

Can anyone on planet earth make Manjaro KDE (KDE 5, Plasma 5) work as a RDP server using xrdp? =|

**Thanks! =D**

Comment: Another solution for RDP client would be Remmina ( https://remmina.org/ ). =D